# Show that $\sigma(\mathcal{G}_1)=\sigma(\mathcal{G}_2)$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $X = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and consider the system of subset of $X$. Let $\mathcal{G}_1=\{\{1,2,3\},\{3,4,5\},\{5,6,7\}\}$ and $\mathcal{G}_2=\{\{1,2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\},\{6,7\}\}$. Show that  $\sigma(\mathcal{G}_1)=\sigma(\mathcal{G}_2)$. You can use that $\sigma(\mathcal{G}_2)\neq \mathcal{P}(X)$

My guess would be to show that $\mathcal{G}_1 \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{G}_2)$ and $\mathcal{G}_2 \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{G}_1)$. I've tried to write out, which elements $\sigma(\mathcal{G}_1)$ and $\sigma(\mathcal{G}_2)$ contains specifically, but that seems to be a long assignment. Any ideas of what I could do otherwise?

Comment: "You can use that $\sigma(\mathcal{G}_2)\neq \mathcal{P}(X)$" If this is a hint to solve the exercise, this is one of the most mysterious I have ever met.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is good, but you don't need to actually write out the sigma algebras -  just show that the sets inside both of the systems can always be obtained through unions and complements of  sets in the other (think about why that's enough)

Comment: If elements in $\mathcal{G}_1$ can be written as unions and complements of elements in $\mathcal{G}_2$ doesn't that per definition imply that $\mathcal{G}_1\subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{G}_2)$, as long as the unions are countable?

Comment: @Jta sorry for the late answer, but yes, that is correct